# vue js failed to pass an array of objects to a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, components, vue-component

I am receiving a json listing, and I am sending this to a component

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    tablaUsuarios: []
},
mounted() {
    axios.get(url + 'listar/')
        .then(res => {
            this.tablaUsuarios = res.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
}
})

Vue.component('tabla-usuario', {
props: ['listaUsuarios'],
template:`<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="usuario in listaUsuarios">
                    <td> {{ usuario.nombre }}</td>
                    <td> {{ usuario.correo }}</td>
                    <td> {{ usuario.password }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>` 
  })
```

In the html

```
<tabla-usuario :listaUsuarios="tablaUsuarios"></tabla-usuario>
```

Technically this is how it should work the problem is that in the DOM it shows me like this

```
<div class="table-responsive" listausuarios="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]">
        <table class="table table-hover text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Could someone who knows the subject tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Could you log the value of `res.data`? Are you getting anything?

Comment: yes, in res.data comes the json with the list of my data

Comment: From the error, it seems like it's returning an array within an array or something. Could you show the structure of the list? You could replace real data with fake data, to protect privacy. Also, I am curious at to why `listausuarios` attribute is showing in the DOM and not `listaUsuarios` as the props are. Could there be a spelling error there?

Comment: ok I realized that if I had a spelling mistake I can't put the prop as `listaUsuarios` if not like `listausuarios`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prop name in the html template needs to be kebab-case (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

like so:

```html
<tabla-usuario :lista-usuarios="tablaUsuarios"></tabla-usuario>
```